# An example of a group operation on the rationals, which is not isomorphic to the additive group

Tags: group-theory, rational-numbers

I'm looking for an example of a group operation on the rationals, which is not isomorphic to the rational additive group. 
Can you find such an example?

Comment: If you don't need an explicit example, but just want to know that there exist such things, then the problem is easy. Take your favourite countable group $G$ that isn't isomorphic to the additive group of rationals, let $f : G \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ denote any bijection, and equip $\mathbb{Q}$ with the unique operations that make $f$ into an isomorphism. Of course, this is not an explicit example, so your question remains.

Comment: First, I do need an explicit example, and second, you start with a countable group which is isomorphic to the additive of the rationals, which is just assuming what you need to show.

Comment: Well like I said, your question still stands. However, if you're wondering: "how do we know such a $G$ exists?" then I can offer a proof sketch to that end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ as an additive group is countable. It has a number of elements of order $2$, which shows it is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}^+$. Construct a bijection between these sets and you're good.